# How to remove top nav bar border

Tags: css, html, navbar, navigationbar

I have a top navigation bar that still has the white borders around. I would like to know how to remove them using css.

This is the css:

```
#nav {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 3em 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: #4c4c4c;
        }

        #nav li {
        float: left; 
        }

        #nav li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
        }

        #nav li a:hover {
        color: grey;
        background-color: white; 
        }
```

This is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <ul id="nav">
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Jean, Check on this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/335L06kr/), is this what you're trying to do ? Credit to @Anuj

Comment: Fiddle and photoshop image will be an excelent for explain us what do you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the question. In `#nav li a` You are giving `border-right: 1px solid #ccc;` remove this and I can not see any border any more. Let me know in case you needed something else.

Answer (score 0):

Change `border-right: 1px solid #ccc;`  to `border-right: 0px solid #ccc;` .Hence,

```
#nav li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        border-right: 0px solid #ccc; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the below code and modify accordingly. The issue will be resolved.

```
#nav li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        }
```